# Mysql variable value as column in select clause

Tags: mysql

I am assigning a variable through below select query output.

```
 select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) 
  from 
    ( select  distinct COLUMN_NAME 
       FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C  
     WHERE table_name = 'ADM_METERQUEUE' 
        AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%maxrate%' 
      order 
         by 1 desc 
      limit 5) as ids 
  INTO @COLUMNS
```

Assigned variable has output like below.

```
select @COLUMNS
```

o/p :: maxrate23,maxrate22,maxrate21,maxrate20,maxrate19

When I am using in select clause i am getting like below.

```
select @COLUMNS from ADM_METERQUEUE where meterqueueid=38
```

o/p :: maxrate23,maxrate22,maxrate21,maxrate20,maxrate19

I want to achieve like below, please let me know how to do it.

**Desired Output::**

```
select maxrate23,maxrate22,maxrate21,maxrate20,maxrate19 from ADM_METERQUEUE where meterqueueid=38;

+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| maxrate23 | maxrate22 | maxrate21 | maxrate20 | maxrate19 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       2   |   7       |  4        |    4      |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)    from      ( select  distinct COLUMN_NAME         FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C        WHERE table_name = 'ADM_METERQUEUE'          AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%maxrate%'        order           by 1 desc        limit 5) as ids    INTO @COLUMNS;

PREPARE stmt FROM 'select ? from ADM_METERQUEUE';

 EXECUTE stmt USING @COLUMNS;
```

o/p :: maxrate23,maxrate22,maxrate21,maxrate20,maxrate19

Still i am getting same column names as output
Server version: 5.6.37-82.2-56-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel82.2, Revision 114f2f2, WSREP version 26.21, wsrep_26.21

Comment: Google Dynamic SQL in MySQL. You should get relevant answers

Comment: Hi @MadhurBhaiya, Thanks for your response.
`select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)    from      ( select  distinct COLUMN_NAME         FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C        WHERE table_name = 'ADM_METERQUEUE'          AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%maxrate%'        order           by 1 desc        limit 5) as ids    INTO @COLUMNS;`
`PREPARE stmt FROM 'select ? from ADM_METERQUEUE';`
` EXECUTE stmt USING @COLUMNS;`

Still i am getting same column names as output
Server version: 5.6.37-82.2-56-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel82.2, Revision 114f2f2, WSREP version 26.21, wsrep_26.21

Answer (score 1):

You are very nearly there, but this section from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) should complete the picture

> Statement names are not case-sensitive. **preparable_stmt is either a
>   string literal or a user variable that contains the text of the SQL
>   statement.** The text must represent a single statement, not multiple
>   statements. Within the statement, ? characters can be used as
>   parameter markers to indicate where data values are to be bound to the
>   query later when you execute it. The ? characters should not be
>   enclosed within quotation marks, even if you intend to bind them to
>   string values. **Parameter markers can be used only where data values
>   should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth**.

In other words, you can use a data value such as `meterqueueid` as a bound variable but not the column identifiers collected in `@COLUMNS`.

Assuming that `meterqueueid` is also being sourced from another variable, then something like this should work

```
SET @mqid = 38;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @COLUMNS, ' FROM ADM_METERQUEUE where meterqueueid=?');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @mqid;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```